# How to open hyperlink on a sheet, and save images folder wise

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation, csv, hyperlink

How do I open hyperlinks on a worksheet and save each image in a different folder?

I am working in Excel. I have 7 sheets of 1000 records each.

In each sheet there are eight columns of hyperlinks (the hyperlinks' url contain links to images). Each record's hyperlink should be opened in a separate windows.

Right now I am using this script to open all hyperlinks at once.

```
Sub OpenHyperLinks()
'Update 20141124
    Dim xHyperlink As Hyperlink
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    For Each xHyperlink In WorkRng.Hyperlinks
        xHyperlink.Follow
    Next
End Sub
```

I can open all the hyperlinks at once, but I really want to open separate chrome windows for each row/record so that I can save each record's image in a separate folders.

See the following image. I want to open the record 10 in one window, 11 in another window and so on.

[image: Please see attached image here]

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator please check now

Comment: Much better. Close vote retracted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code. It did work on my Windows 7 64 Bit with Chrome Version 62.0.3202.75.

Usually Chrome opens subsequent URLs in a new Tab rather than a new Window. So you may not be able to control this behavior if you use `Hyperlink.Follow` method in your VBA. Trick is to call a new instance of Chrome using Shell function after each Row is processed so that subsequent URLs open in that new instance and so on.

While this code did work at my end, it may or may not work exactly as expected subject to Windows OS/Chrome Versions and the way it's designed. So do give it a try and report back.

Moreover using Shell may slightly speed up URL opening and most importantly Chrome will still open a valid Text URL even if it's not actually resolved as a URL in Excel document just in case.

```
  Sub OpenHyperLinks()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim xHyperlink As String
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim col_counter As Integer
    Dim row_counter As Integer
    Dim pHandle
    Const Chrome_Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe"
    'Set above Constant Chrome_Path to match  Chrome.exe location on your PC
    counter = 0
    row_counter = 0
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Select Range", Type:=8)
    If WorkRng.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    col_counter = WorkRng.Columns.Count
    For Each cell In WorkRng
        If counter = 0 Then
            pHandle = Shell(Chrome_Path)
        End If
        xHyperlink = cell.Value
        If xHyperlink = "" Then
        Else
            pHandle = Shell(Chrome_Path & " -url " & xHyperlink)
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
        If counter = col_counter Then
           counter = 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

There is no much validation in the code. Just in case you cancel at the InputBox, the sub exits as there's nothing to process and in case Hyperlink is blank it will be skipped. Set Chrome_Path constant to match the location of the Chrome.exe on your PC, just in case it's installed to a different folder/partition on your PC.

If you have hundreds of URLs to process, it might eventually slow down your PC though as several Chrome instances shall occupy in the memory. Alternatively you may pause after every record using `MsgBox` or so and manually close the open instance of Chrome after your work with it is done.